# Applescript open all file in folder one by one

Tags: applescript

I'm only a beginner sorry if my question look stupid.

Right now I'm trying to write a script that convert all my .webarchive to .html, so I end up using application called "iCab" to open .webarchive and save it to .html

Here is the question I've all my .webarchive in save folder and I need a loop to open it all one by one, so I can put this fragment of code inside the loop

```
tell application "iCab" to open file file_name
tell application "iCab" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iCab"
        click menu item "Save As…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        key code 76
        click menu item "Close Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's difficult to ascertain exactly what your challenge is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to convert the files from Finder file objects to aliases.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set fl to files of folder POSIX file "/Users/username/Folder/" as alias list
end tell
repeat with f in fl
    tell application "iCab"
        open f
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iCab"
            click menu item "Save As…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            keystroke return
            click menu item "Close Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: I've another question.If you don't mind me asking.I tried to make the code prompt for the folder, but I got an error message say 
"Finder got an error: Can’t make alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Angeloid:Desktop:html:" into type integer."
How can I fixed it?

Comment: In AppleScript Editor, Right-Click (Control-Click) in your source code and select the item "Iterate Items" where you will find some code snippets to paste into your source code. It contains the code your'e looking for (selecting a folder).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to every file of folder "Mac OS X:Users:Angeloid:Desktop:yourFolder"
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    --insert your code here
end repeat
```

EDIT to include choose folder:

```
tell application "Finder" to set myFiles to every file of (choose folder)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    tell application "iCab"
        open file file_name
        activate
    end tell
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iCab"
            click menu item "Save As…" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            key code 76
            click menu item "Close Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end repeat
```